# Combine several data frames into a single data frame

Tags: r

I need to iterate over a vector and call a function. The result of this function is a data frame and I want to combine all the data frames returned by the function for each value in the vector into one data frame.

Consider the example below. I want to apply getDetails to each value of vec and combine the results.

```
vec = c(1,2)
getDetails = function(match){
  if (match == 1)
    return (data.frame(Player=c(1,2), Score = c(3,4)))
  else
    return (data.frame(Player=c(1,2), Score = c(7,8)))
}
```

What I would like returned is this:

```
  Player Score
1      1     3
2      2     4
3      1     7
4      2     8
```

I tried sapply but that returns a data frame of the same length as the vector (so each row is a data frame instead of a vector). Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(vec, getDetails))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in `plyr`,

```
ldply(vec, getDetails)
```